# Please remove the Unicoins self-destruct mechanism (if any) so we can still set our clocks to April 1st 2 weeks from now and still play!

Tags: feature-request, support, unicoins

As I type this in Australia it's 8:45AM on April the 2nd, and all of the Unicoin awesomeness I was able to access yesterday has vanished.

I understand that if I confuse my computer's idea of what time it is *ever so slightly*, Unicoins will come back... but I am slightly depressed by the idea of this, since I know there's probably a self-destruct sequence hiding somewhere which will activate once it isn't April 1 anywhere anymore.

My feature-request is that the self-destruct sequence be turned in on itself. At least for a while. :D

As a contingency plan in case this does not occur, however, JS hackers unite to [help reverse-engineer Unicoin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227948/help-me-reverse-engineer-unicoin)!

Comment: AAArgh! no!!! boohooo!!!  now I need a new mouse after wearing out the left button, mining all day long in vain..... snif...

Comment: come to america. weez still gots dee unicoins

Comment: At first I completely forgot that it was April Fools day and was all excited with the new yet random unicorn feature. I started mining so that I could by the reputation multiplier for 10 more points. After I got it and remembered that today is April 1, I was a bit disappointed that I wasted 5 minutes of life. It's still fun though.