# Will Unicoins stay?

Tags: discussion, unicoins

I've heard terrible rumors that these Unicoins are just an "April fools joke".  I seriously doubt that, because Unicoins are awesome!  However, if it's true, then will they go?

Please don't remove them, I love Unicoins!

Comment: hahah i have more rep than all y'all!

Comment: You're picture is not wobbuffet is it also part of the April FOols Joke?

Comment: @AsshO.Le No..?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I come to you from Australia, where due to time zone quirks, we are several hours into the future. I come to warn you that Unicoins are no more.

Overnight, the Unicorns decided they no longer wished to trade with those countries that do not recognise Unicorns as citizens.

I-In fact... I think they decided they were a bit fed up with us.

I hear them coming. I hear their rainbow tanks.

*Protect your loved ones. You have but hours.*

Comment: I'm in Australia too, and I can confirm this. **Flee! Flee across the International Date Line while you still have time!**

Comment: I will hop aboard an airplane that continually flies due west, away from the dreaded sunrise. Perpetual unicorns!

Comment: @Pëkka You will need a very fast airplane.

Comment: @BlueIce Or a trip to the Arctic Circle.

Comment: @michaelb958 But the [Arctic Circle uses UTC](http://www.thenakedscientists.com/forum/index.php?topic=17173.0) :( Better go with [Antarctica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Antarctica).

Comment: @BlueIce The point of going up there is you don't need to go quite as fast to stay ahead of *them*.

Comment: @michaelb958 Oh.

Comment: Quickly, people!  Let's build a time machine and warn the past not to take it for granted!

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to worry about Unicoins leaving.

Unicoins will stay forever... in our hearts.

<sub>Actually, an effort to keep Unicoins forever in real life can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227948/help-me-reverse-engineer-unicoin).</sub>

Comment: And in retrieved JS files added to my browser's TamperMonkey extension (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227948/help-me-reverse-engineer-unicoin/).

Answer (score 0):

I hope the moderators will not get away with this by just saying it was a joke. If it were, they have been lying. It is offending. I don't understand what is funny about it.

Comment: I hope it is a joke. It's sick to introduce "currency" into a forum where information is supposed to be free. Nothing is free I hear you scream back!? You wanna bet!?

Comment: @Fernando68 I agree. I hope it is not real from the point of view as you mention. But at the same time, I hope it is not a joke from the point of view that I don't feel comfortable being told a lie.